# URL with long query string not working for IE ,but working for FF and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, query-string, maxlength

I have a URL with long query string, the query string length is more than its standard limit (2048). So I have changed the Request filter setting for `maxQueryString` in **IIS** . URL is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but it's not working for IE 8 and 9.

Comment: You should take different approach like POST implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The default limit is 16,384 characters (yes, Microsoft's web server accepts longer URLs than Microsoft's web browser). This is configurable.
Switching to a POST request simply because there's too much data to fit in a POST request makes little sense

Comment: Can u suggest one Example